# CDF of multivariate hypergeometric distribution

Tags: distributions, hypergeometric-distribution

I am trying to find the CDF of the multivariate hypergeometric distribution, but was unable to come across any sources. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The cdf has no closed form.

Comment: Hello. Thank you @Xi'an Would it be possible to show how it could be calculated /derived? Or a link to where it has been derived?